# When you run jest --coverage, what does the Branches column do/mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I ran my tests and this is what I received:

`---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |        0 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 Search        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.js     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 SearchResults |      100 |        0 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.js     |      100 |        0 |      100 |      100 |                 4 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        4.678s`

I've changed something and now I have 0% on Branch column but I don't know what it means in order to improve it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Conditional statements create branches of code which may not be executed (e.g. if/else). This metric tells you how many of your branches have been executed.

Comment: Oooo I see! Thank you!

Comment: Btw I did upvote but I only have 6 reputation points. I had 8 before but someone downvoted this question. I need 15 before the vote shows :(

Comment: One would assume that this is written somewhere in the jest documentation, yet I found nothing...

Comment: How does it make sense that 100% of lines were executed while no code branch was tested? let's say we have an IF that branches to `code1` if `true` and to `code2` if `false`. If 100% lines were executed then both of the branches `code1` and `code2` were executed, right? so don't we expect to have %brance bigger than 0 in the report?

Comment: You should write code which tests both branches so then you'd have 100% coverage, not the other way around

Answer (score 7):

A branch exists for any block, line, statement, or part of a statement which may be skipped during execution. This can be the result of if-then-else, switch-case-default, or the ternary operator.

There are many ways one could end up with 100% line coverage but less than 100% branch coverage. If the code is well organized, the most likely explanation is that a branch exists which has no exclusive lines of code (in other words, there is some condition that causes code to be skipped, but does not run any alternate or additional code instead). For example, take the following function:

```
function invertIf(val,flag) {
  if (flag) {
    val = val * -1;
  }
  return val;
}
```

If a single test is run with flag equal to true, then every line and statement will be evaluated (giving 100% coverage) but it will achieve get 100% branch coverage because the possibility exists that some lines will not be executed (when flag equals false) and there is no test case for it.

One could get statement coverage that is less than line coverage if there are multiple statements per line. In this scenario, you could also get <100% branch coverage. For example:

```
function isFoo(a) {
  if (a=='Foo') {return true;} else {return false;}
}
```

One test case will achieve 100% line coverage, but will not achieve 100% statement or branch coverage. Although this is probably a symptom that your code needs to be re-organized. (Just as you could have multiple statements on one line, you may also have multiple lines for one statement)

It is also possible to put multiple branches into a *single* statement using the ternary operator, such as in the following example:

```
function isBar(a) {
  return a == 'Bar' ? true : false}
}
```

One could write a logically equivalent function using if-then-else, but unlike if-then-else, use of the ternary operator is considered a single statement, with two branches (or more if ternary operators are nested, but if you are doing this then you probably shouldn't be using them)

All that said, I don't know how you get 0% branch coverage while having 100% statement coverage. If you executed 100% of statements in the code, you must have executed at least one branch out of a finite number of branches. My best guess is that there is a line of code that is executable but is too complex or uses something too esoteric that the analyzer doesn't know how to count branches for. In these situations it may just default to 0% since you would have to manually review branch coverage if the analyzer is unable to. However, I could not come with any example that exhibits this behavior.